# Why am I getting error while using Perfect-Curl on Mac?

Tags: macos, curl, networking, apple-developer

I encountered an issue while attempting to integrate the Perfect Curl package into my MacOS project. The error message "Cannot find 'CURLOPT_FTP_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT' in scope" arises during the compilation process, halting the successful addition of the package to the project.

macOS version: 12.6.2
Xcode version: 14.2
Perfect Curl package version: 5.0.0

This problem prevents the Perfect Curl package from integrating smoothly into MacOS projects, affecting curl-dependent functionalities.

I tried reloading the package, using different versions of Perfect-Curl from "https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-CURL.git". I tried changing my Xcode version, but the issue isn't resolved. Any leads would be appreciated. The same code worked in another system.

Comment: For readers to help, they need a "Hello World" version of this they can test with. See [mcve] . Did you look on [apple.se] to see if this is a known problem? Good luck.